# Latex table missing number error

Tags: tables, errors, multirow

[image]I am trying to make a table in the same format as above in Miktex yet I keep getting errors such as missing number treated as zero. The table should have some empty blocks I do not know if that is causing the problem.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
Test was&  &1 & 2 & 3 & ... & N\\
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{performed} & a_i & + & + $ -  & ... & +\\
 & b_i & +  & - & -  & ...$ + \\
\hline
 \multirow{2}{not performed} & a'_i & ? & ? & ? $ ... & ?\\
 & b'_i & ? & ? & ? $ ... & ?\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{align}
```

Comment: if you want help with an error messag eshow the exact error an dprovide a test file, it is very hard to help otherwise. You have only posted a fragment that we can not run but it is very odd, why do you have `align` with no alignment points around the `tabular` ?

Comment: `tabular` cells are text mode so `a_i` will be an error, perhaps you intended to use `array` rather than `tabular` ?

Comment: Additionally, both `\multirow` commands are missing their second argument, which determines the width. You probably want to use `\multirow{2}{*}{performed}` instead of `\multirow{2}{performed}`. A sketch of the ecpected output would also really help here. Could you add one to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following is at least somewhat close to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l||>{$}c<{$}|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Test was                       &      & 1 & 2 & 3 & ... & N \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{performed}     & a_i  & + & + & - & ... & + \\
                               & b_i  & + & - & - & ... & + \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{not performed} & a'_i & ? & ? & ? & ... & ? \\
                               & b'_i & ? & ? & ? & ... & ? \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `array` and `w{c}{<width>}` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \[
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{array}{ |p{7em}||*{6}{w{c}{2em}|} }
 \hline
Test was    &     & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & N   \\
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{=}{performed} 
            & a_i & + & + & - & \dots & +   \\
            & b_i & + & - & - & \dots & +   \\
\hline
 \multirow{2}{=}{not performed} 
            & a'_i & ? & ? & ? & \dots & ?  \\
            & b'_i & ? & ? & ? & \dots & ?  \\
 \hline
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]